# Show that the sequence is convergent to $(a_1a_2^2)^{1/3}$.

Tags: real-analysis

> If $\{ a_n\}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that $$a_n=\sqrt{a_{n-1}a_{n-2}},n>2$$ then show that the sequence is convergent to $(a_1a_2^2)^{1/3}$.

How I proceed: Take square of $a_n$ so I get $a_n^2=a_{n-1}a_{n-2} \implies a_n^3=a_na_{n-1}a_{n-2}$. Then stuck. Please help.

Comment: Write $a_n = a_1^{\alpha_n}\cdot a_2^{\beta_n}$. Find a recurrence for $\alpha_n$ and $\beta_n$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Please explain it more. I am unable to solve the problem with your hint.

Comment: $$a_n^2a_{n-1}=a_{n-1}^2a_{n-2}=\cdots=a_2^2a_1.$$

Answer (score 4):

Let $b_n=\ln (a_n)$

So, $2b_n=b_{n-1}+b_{n-2}$

Using [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving), $b_n=A+B\left(-\frac12\right)^n$ where $A,B$ are arbitrary constants

$n=1\implies b_1=A-\frac B2$

$n=2\implies b_2= A+\frac B4$

$\implies B=\frac43(b_2-b_1)$ and $A=\frac{b_1+2b_2}3$

$\implies b_n=\frac{b_1+2b_2}3+\frac43(b_2-b_1)\left(-\frac12\right)^n$

$\implies\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n=\frac{b_1+2b_2}3$ as $\lim_{n\to\infty}r^n=0$ if $|r|<1$

$\implies\lim_{n\to\infty} \ln(a_n)=\frac{\ln a_1+2\ln a_2}3=\ln (a_1\cdot a_2^2)^{\frac13} $

Answer (score 1):

Let $r$ be a positive real number, and let $b_n=ra_n$.  If one sequence has a limit, then so does the other, with the limits differing by a factor of $r$.  Note that the sequence of $b$'s satisfies the same recursion as the $a$'s:

$$b_n=ra_n=r\sqrt{a_{n-1}a_{n-2}}=\sqrt{(ra_{n-1})(ra_{n-2})}=\sqrt{b_{n-1}b_{n-2}}$$

Now let $r=(a_1a_2^2)^{-1/3}$.  Then we have

$$b_1={a_1\over(a_1a_2^2)^{1/3}}=\left({a_1\over a_2} \right)^{2/3} $$

and

$$b_2={a_2\over(a_1a_2^2)^{1/3}}=\left({a_2\over a_1} \right)^{1/3}= b_1^{-1/2}$$

Let's just write $b$ for $b_1$.  Then by the recursion, we have

$$\begin{align}
b_3&=\sqrt{b_2b_1}=(b^{-1/2}b)^{1/2}=b^{1/4}\\
b_4&= \sqrt{b_3b_2}=(b^{1/4}b^{-1/2})^{1/2}=b^{-1/8}\\
b_5&=\sqrt{b_4b_3}=(b^{-1/8}b^{1/4})^{1/2}=b^{1/16}\\
&\vdots
\end{align}$$

It's an easy induction to see that $b_{n+1}=b^{(-1/2)^n}$, and consequently easy to see that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n=1$.  From this it follows that the sequence of $a$'s converges, and

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n={1\over r} = (a_1a_2^2)^{1/3}$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is an solution
with an explicit formula
for $a_n$
in terms of $a_1$ and $a_2$.
Letting $b_n = \ln a_n$,
the formula is
$b_n
=\frac{2b_{2}+b_{1}}{3} + (-1)^n\frac{b_{2}-b_{1}}{3\cdot 2^{n-2}}
$,
so
$a_n 
= \sqrt[3]{a_2^2a_1} (a_2/a_1)^{(-1)^n/3\cdot 2^{n-2}} 
$.

Start as
lab-bhattacharjee,
with
$b_n = \ln a_n$,
so
$b_n = \frac{b_{n-1}+b_{n-2}}{2}$
with
$b_1 = \ln a_1$,
$b_2 = \ln a_2$.

Iterating,
using
$b_{n-k} = 2b_{n-k-2}-b_{n-k-1}$,

$\begin{align}
b_n
&=\frac{b_{n-1}+b_{n-2}}{2}\\
&= \frac{\frac{b_{n-2}+b_{n-3}}{2}+\frac{b_{n-3}+b_{n-4}}{2}}{2}\\
&= \frac{b_{n-2}+2b_{n-3}+b_{n-4}}{4}\\ 
&= \frac{b_{n-2}+2b_{n-3}+2b_{n-2}-b_{n-3}}{4}\\ 
&= \frac{3b_{n-2}+b_{n-3}}{4}\\ 
&= \frac{3\frac{b_{n-3}+b_{n-4}}{2}+\frac{b_{n-4}+b_{n-5}}{2}}{4}\\ 
&= \frac{3b_{n-3}+4b_{n-4}+b_{n-5}}{8}\\ 
&= \frac{3b_{n-3}+4b_{n-4}+2b_{n-3}-b_{n-4}}{8}\\ 
&= \frac{5b_{n-3}+3b_{n-4}}{8}\\ 
\end{align}
$.

From this, it looks like,
for each $k \ge 1$,
$b_n = \frac{r_kb_{n-k}+s_kb_{n-k-1}}{2^k}$
for some integers $r_k$ and $s_k$.
If this is so,

$\begin{align}
b_n
&=\frac{r_kb_{n-k}+s_kb_{n-k-1}}{2^k}\\
&=\frac{r_k\frac{b_{n-k-1}+b_{n-k-2}}{2}+s_k\frac{b_{n-k-2}+b_{n-k-3}}{2}}{2^k}\\ 
&=\frac{r_kb_{n-k-1}+r_kb_{n-k-2}+s_kb_{n-k-2}+s_kb_{n-k-3}}{2^{k+1}}\\ 
&=\frac{r_kb_{n-k-1}+(r_k+s_k)b_{n-k-2}+s_k(2b_{n-k-1}-b_{n-k-2})}{2^{k+1}}\\ 
&=\frac{(r_k+2s_k)b_{n-k-1}+r_kb_{n-k-2}}{2^{k+1}}\\ 
\end{align}
$

Therefore
$r_{k+1} = r_k+2s_k$
and
$s_k=r_k$.

Using this, we get
$(k, r_k, s_k) = (1, 1, 1), (2, 3, 1), (3, 5, 3), (4, 11, 5), (5, 21, 11),
(6, 43, 11)$.

From this, it looks like
$r_k+s_k = 2^k$
and
$r_k-2s_k = (-1)^k$.

This is easily proved by induction.
If it is true for $k$,
$r_{k+1}+s_{k+1}
=r_k+2s_k+r_k
=2(r_k+2s_k)
=2^{k+1}
$
and
$r_{k+1}-2s_{k+1}
 =r_k+2s_k-2r_k
 =-(r_k+s_k)
=(-1)^{k+1}
 $ .

From these,
we can solve for $r_k$ and $s_k$.

Subtracting them,
$3s_k = 2^k-(-1)^k$,
so
$s_k = \frac{2^k-(-1)^k}{3}$,

Then
$r_k = 2\frac{2^k-(-1)^k}{3}+(-1)^k
=\frac{2^{k+1}+(-1)^k}{3}
$.

Therefore

$\begin{align}
b_n 
&= \frac{r_kb_{n-k}+s_kb_{n-k-1}}{2^k}\\
&= \frac{\frac{2^{k+1}+(-1)^k}{3}b_{n-k}+\frac{2^k-(-1)^k}{3}b_{n-k-1}}{2^k} \\
&= \frac{(2^{k+1}+(-1)^k)b_{n-k}+(2^k-(-1)^k)b_{n-k-1}}{3\cdot 2^k} \\ 
\text{putting }k = n-2\\
&= \frac{(2^{n-1}+(-1)^{n-2})b_{2}+(2^{n-2}-(-1)^{n-2})b_{1}}{3\cdot 2^{n-2}} \\ 
&= \frac{2^{n-1}b_{2}+2^{n-2}b_{1}}{3\cdot 2^{n-2}} 
+ \frac{(-1)^{n-2}b_{2}-(-1)^{n-2}b_{1}}{3\cdot 2^{n-2}} \\
&= \frac{2b_{2}+b_{1}}{3} + \frac{(-1)^{n}b_{2}-(-1)^{n}b_{1}}{3\cdot 2^{n-2}} \\ 
&= \frac{2b_{2}+b_{1}}{3} + (-1)^n\frac{b_{2}-b_{1}}{3\cdot 2^{n-2}} \\ 
\end{align} 
$

This shows, finally, that
$b_n \to \frac{2b_{2}+b_{1}}{3}$
so, as desired,
$a_n \to \sqrt[3]{a_2^2a_1}$.

Note that,
from the exact expression for $b_n$,
$a_n 
= \sqrt[3]{a_2^2a_1}
e^{(-1)^n\frac{b_{2}-b_{1}}{3\cdot 2^{n-2}}}
= \sqrt[3]{a_2^2a_1} (a_2/a_1)^{(-1)^n/3\cdot 2^{n-2}} 
$.